# What video resolution / specifications does Facebook support?

Tags: facebook, video

Facebook appears to have changed its video upload policies recently. Can anyone advise where this might be documented?

I've got a FB app that publishes two types of videos to a FB page from a museum exhibition. One of these types - recorded on iPods - are still publishing fine. The other, server generated video from a single image and recorded audio is not being accepted this month but was working last month. 
I've ruled out software errors - the files in question are no longer accepted via manual upload.

The spec of the videos being rejected are
H.264, 512 × 512, Millions
AAC, Mono, 44.100 kHz
FPS 15 or 30

Any suggestions? The spec is identical to files that are accepted so my hunch is that FB has changed some policy and disallowing video that does not contain any moving image to cut out audio copyright infringements. In this instance, the audio is all legally collected, there is no information provided on why the files are being rejected and we can't find any stated guideline or policy that would justify why this is happneing.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted video types are listed here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/videos/#publish

Check if your video matches the specs.

Comment: Better URL (to latest api) is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos#publish

Comment: At the time of posting my answer v2.1 was the most actual version